# Create Registration form in Mule

Tags: mule

I am a newbie to [MuleESB](http://www.mulesoft.org). I want to create a registration form using Mule but I am stuck.

I don't know how to display index.jsp on start-up of your application. I already gone through BookStore example but couldn't get efficient information.

I created a web.xml under `src->main->app->webapps->WEB-INF->web.xml`

```
*<web-app....>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>*
```

Any Help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a web application context directory under: `src->main->app->webapps->WEB-INF->web.xml`, ie you should have something like: `src->main->app->webapps->my-context->WEB-INF->web.xml`.

Follow the BookStore example carefully and you should have no difficulty reaching your goal.